# Java Code without Try and Catch

Tags: java, global

I have the code:

```
public class RssReader {
    private File dataFile = new File("data.dat");
    private  FileInputStream dataStream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
    boolean fileExists;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

My question is, can I put FileInputStream or any code that requires Try/catch as a global function?

Comment: I think it's time you use an IDE e.g. Eclipse.

Comment: You have initialization code that can throw an `IOEexception` there is no scope to add the `throws` to and no place for a `try` and `catch`

Comment: Warning. Warning. Warning. Religions IDE war. Warning.

Comment: I recommend NetBeans ;-)

Comment: I recommend [ALL IDES] over [Anything Else]

Comment: Beware the IDEs of March!

Comment: Thankfully it's June. My Caesar cipher can rest easy.

Comment: @ArifSamin DevC++ is no longer being actively maintained, although I liked it in its day, does it work with java as well? I must admit I only ever used it for C

Comment: @RichardTingle of course it wont work with java. :)

Comment: @ArifSamin It did seem unlikely but I didnt want to assume. It was your question "why not use DevC++ [with this java question]" that confused me

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. you can declare that `main` method throws an `Exception` of any kind, i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
}
```

And you can omit the try-catch block in the code.

I would highly suggest NOT doing that, though. First of all, try-catch blocks exist for a reason. They are here to catch exceptions that you might foresee but have no control of (i.e. bad file format). Second of all, they will let you close the streams in `finally` blocks even if the exception happens.

Comment: Uhm, `Exception` is a little coarse. At least reduce the scope to IOException here ;)

Comment: There is another problem with accessing the `dataStream` instance variable inside a static method (like `main()`).

Comment: That's what I intended to tell, but I've just realized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you let your constructor throws the exception :

```
class RssReader {
    private File dataFile = new File("data.dat");
    private  FileInputStream dataStream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
    boolean fileExists;

    RssReader()throws IOException{}

}
```

Then each time you will construct a new `RssReader` object, the method that handle this construction should throws it too (like darijan said), or you can create a try-catch block in this method :

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {
    RssReader r = new RssReader();
}
```

or :

```
public void someMethod() {
    RssReader r;
    try {
        r = new RssReader();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add that code by signing the method with throws Exception. But it is not recommended when you have an stream reader or something like that because often you gotta close the stream or flush the writers.

I think you should think about it when you need to open or close a stream object.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do and several you can't:

1. You can't initialize a variable with code that can throw a checked exception. The compiler will complain. So your line beginning `private FileInputStream ...` is illegal.
2. You can't use the instance variables inside the static `main()` method. The compiler will again complain once you put `... dataStream ...` inside `main()`.
3. You can put a `throws IOException` on the main method.

---

**One way** to deal with these things is to do this:

```
public class RssReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dataFile = new File("data.dat");
        FileInputStream dataStream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
        boolean fileExists;
        ... use the variables here ...
    }
}
```

which will toss you out to the command line if you run the program and, for example, the file doesn't exist. An error message and stack trace will be printed if that happens.

What I did up there is move all the variables into the scope of the `main()` method. Then I added the `throws` on the method so it will let whatever basic part of Java calls `main()` handle the exception.

---

Or you could do something **another way** like this:

```
public class RssReader {
    private static File dataFile = new File("data.dat");
    private static FileInputStream dataStream;
    static {
        try {
            dataStream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // this isn't a best practice
        }
    }
    static boolean fileExists;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ... use the variables here ...
    }
}
```

which will do the same thing if there is a problem with finding the file. Out to the command line and print messages.

This hides the possible checked exception inside a static initializer block with a try-catch around it. The checked exception is turned into an unchecked exception. It also makes all the variable static so they can be used in the static method `main()`

---

One more possible solution that's **an even better way**:

```
public class RssReader {
    private File dataFile = new File("data.dat");
    private FileInputStream dataStream;
    boolean fileExists;

    public RssReader() throws IOException {
        dataStream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
    }

    public void doTheWork() {
        ... use all the variables here ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           reader = new RssReader();
           reader.doTheWork();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("File 'data.dat' not found. Exiting ...");
        }
    }
}
```

which is the one I like best. It gives you control over what happens if an exception happens so we print an informative message and tell them the program is finished. All the variables are instance variables inside the object instance created in the `main()` method. Main does almost nothing but create the instance and tell it to get to work. Main also decides what to do if it fails.

The changes are to move everything to instance scope and out of static scope, except catching the fatal exception. You can leave your variables at the top where they are easy to read. The method that does the work is given a name to describe what it does.